# Docker mount directories to container rules

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am running a docker container and have to mount two directories to the docker container. One is for data while the other is for libraries. Let's name the data directory on my host as A, library directory on my host as B, data directory on container as A', and library directory on container as B'.

Note that A' is under /opt and B' is under /usr. Both A and B are empty folders.

When I mount them with -v tag, some strange thing happens. B' is totally covered by B. In other words, it becomes an empty folder. All initial files inside it are hidden. However, I can see files from A' in my host directory A. It seems like A and A' share data with each other but B' is just override by B.

What's the reason of this?

Update 1: here is the command I used

```
sudo docker run --name geoservertest -d -p 8085:8080 -v /home/zhangj/geoserver_data:/opt/geoserver/data_dir -v /home/zhangj/geoserver_lib:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib gistic/geoserver
```

In the code, geoserver_data is A, data_dir is A', geoserver_lib is B and lib is B'.

Comment: Check commands ordering in your Dockerfile.  
`COPY /usr /usr
VOLUME /usr`
And 

`VOLUME /usr
COPY /usr /usr`

has totally different result

Comment: I don't have a dockerfile yet unfortunately. Currently I am using a single command to create container from image. I used two -v tags in the command. I do -v tag for both of them exactly the same way. @Bukharov Sergey

Comment: Can you post exact docker command you are using to run container?

Comment: Of course, here is the command I use. sudo docker run --name geoservertest -d -p 8085:8080 -v /home/zhangj/geoserver_data:/opt/geoserver/data_dir -v /home/zhangj/geoserver_lib:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib gistic/geoserver  I also added it in my post, which is easier to read. @Tomasz Domazal